Unable to read a dxf file using read() method
i have a fast api application where the dxf file is uploaded. It is passed to a function to read the contents. I have used read() method to read the file as bytes, then converted to string by using .decode("utf-8") and the converted it to string io object using io.StringIo. Finally this stringio object is passed as  the argument to ezdxf.read(). But an error is thrown is ezdxf.lldxf.const.DXFStructureError: Invalid binary data near line: 7618.' Please guide me to resolve this.
dxf_bytes=await upload_file.read()
dxf_string=dxf_bytes.decode('utf-8')
dxf_stringio=io.StringIO(dxf_string)
doc=ezdxf.read(dxf_stringio)


Can't you just pass dxf_bytes to ezdxf.decode_base64?

The DXF file contains binary data, which is common in DXF files. Here's a modified approach you can try:
import io
import ezdxf

async def read_dxf_file(upload_file):
    dxf_bytes = await upload_file.read()
    doc = ezdxf.read(io.BytesIO(dxf_bytes))
    return doc

Assuming you have a FastAPI endpoint where you handle file uploads
@app.post("/upload/")
async def upload_dxf_file(upload_file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        doc = await read_dxf_file(upload_file)
        # Do whatever you want with the DXF document 'doc'
        return {"message": "DXF file processed successfully"}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"error": str(e)}

In this modified version, I'm using io.BytesIO instead of io.StringIO to read the bytes directly as a binary stream. This should handle binary data properly, which might be causing the error you're encountering with ezdxf.read().

I have modified the code as mentioned above but I still get the error "a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".

hi @me280872 did you find a solution ? I'm currently facing the same issu
